# IPv4 and IPv6 In a Single Network Segment

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I need someone to back me up, or prove me wrong, in regard to the comments I've made some time ago.  Here is the original thread:

[dual-stack ipv6/ipv4 on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277536/dual-stack-ipv6-ipv4-on-localhost/2277596#2277596)

Basically, I'd like to know if we can have 2 different kinds of IP addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) running on the same network segment WITHOUT any address translation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any problems: IPv4 and IPv6 can share a transport layer such as Ethernet without causing problems. Furthermore, there are many systems that can support both v4 and v6 protocol stacks concurrently.

Of course, to get any communications going between IPv4 and IPv6 nodes, one must go through a gateway (e.g. 4to6).

Comment: Ethernet is on the data link layer, I suppose.  Anyway, you've answered my question as I wanted to know if they can share the same network segment (not physical linkage) so that they can talk to each other without translation.  Thanks a lot!  :)

Comment: re: "Data Link layer": you are thinking in terms of the OSI *model* which doesn't really real networks nowadays. The term "transport" is commonly used in networking to represent the carriage of information and this is much independent from the OSI terminology of "Transport layer".